# Excess data on corrupted rar file

Tags: data-recovery, rar

Using PhotoRec, a recovery tool, on a damaged data hard drive, I rescued a 30GB .rar file. When I unrar it, the output is a ~6MB folder.

(EDIT: the unzipped 6MB folder is the correct, complete set of contents of a .rar file I had. However, the .rar file clearly contains more information than that.)

I suspect (hope?) some unrelated data has hitched a ride after the EOF of the rar. If so, I'd be very interested in checking what is there, and eventually separating it from the compressed folder.

The size of the file makes it impractical to look at the contents with a text editor and find any file format tags etc that could hint at what's inside / where to split. I haven't been able to find a tool that does it automatically.

Is there one? Preferably one that runs on Windows, but any Linux tool will do.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a binary file with a text editor won't provide you any insight.
Any hex editor will do.
Nevertheless, even using a hex editor, looking at compressed data won't help you further.

Winrar itself has a repair function for its archives.
A couple of third party vendors claim that they are able to repair rar-archives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure it applies to my problem, though; the file itself is not corrupt, just presumably has other info appended at the end. Winrar's repair correctly gets rid of the extra data, but I want the exact opposite. This extra data is not part of the rar file itself, so it should not be compressed -- and I think file tags would show up in a text (not hex) editor. The point is moot anyway, since I don't know of a text editor that can handle a 30GB file :)

Comment: HxD (Hex editor mentioned in Roberts answer) is capable of this. Other Large Text File Options: https://stackoverflow.com/q/159521/3654325 . Also, just try dropping it onto a browser, if the browser thinks it's a text file it will likely display (very) big files.

Answer (score 0):

Such a large file is usually written on disc as one continuous file, instead it is written in fragments.

PhotoRec is a file carver which scans for file headers and based on the info in it calculates the file size. This only works for files that has been written as continuous block to disk. In case the RAR file has been generated on this disk then most likely it consists of hundred of fragments. If if has been copied from a different drive of still may consist of up to a dozen file fragments.

In your case I would assume that most of the data in the recovered file is just data of other files and thus the file is not corrupt but just random data which can't be repaired or recovered.

File carving only works for small files that are written as one block to disk. Use a hex editor like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) (freeware can open files of any size) to see the content. If you encounter lot of readable text blocks you know that the content does not belong to the RAR file.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, but the rar file was encrypted. I was able to access a very small part of the extra data by using the recovery option (`rar r file.rar`) and entering the *wrong* password. It generated a new rar file with data that wasn't supposed to be in that particular archive.